# Why can a non-const member function be invoked on a constant structure?

Tags: c++, constants, type-mismatch

The program below compiles (with gcc), but should it?  I would have thought that V1(1.0) created below is a constant, and so a non const method could not be invoked on it.

```
class V{
  double v;
 public:
  V(double v1){ v = v1;}
  void clear(){ v = 0;}
};

int main(){
  V(1.0).clear();
}
```

Compare this to a function "void f(int &t){}" which cannot be called as "f(1)", because 1 is a constant which cannot be a value for a non-const reference t.

Comment: temporary != constant (as you discovered)

Comment: What here is supposed to be a constant structure?

Comment: I'm not clear how anything can be `const`. The keyword doesn't appear anywhere in your code. Also, member initialization syntax.

Comment: You also might want to look into r-value references (C++11) for your `void f(int &t){}` assumption. A bit different, but very similar concept.

Answer (score 3):

`V(1.0)` calls the constructor, which initializes `double v1` **by copy**. So you have a temporary with a copy of the literal.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing constants with r-values. `f(1)` would be illegal because `1` is not an l-value. `V(1.0)` is not a constant, but a temporary.

Comment: I was supposing that temporaries should not appear as l-values.